# GCP metrics dashboard from cloudsql

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, dashboard, metrics

How to create an admin/monitoring dashboard in gcp based on tables data in CloudSql - SqlServer?

A simple use case would be:

1. Table - Students
2. Table - Books

Want to have a dashboard to display:

1. how many students have checked out a book?
2. What is the current inventory of books?

How can I have these metrics on a dashboard, so no need to go to database and query table(s)?

Comment: What have you tried or investigated so far?

Comment: Hi @peacefulmember, I have posted an answer. Can you check if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

The [monitoring dashboard](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/monitor-instance#cloud-monitoring) for Cloud SQL in the Google Cloud Console is used for monitoring the [metrics of Cloud SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/admin-api/metrics) to keep an eye on the general health of the primary and replica of the Cloud SQL instance. So it is not for creating a dashboard based on the data in the database of the Cloud SQL instance.

To create a dashboard based on the data inside the Cloud SQL database you can use [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com). With Google Data Studio you can use only Cloud SQL for MySQL as Cloud SQL for SQL Server and Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL is not supported currently. You can find the detailed steps to connect to Cloud SQL for MySQL from Google Data Studio [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020436?hl=en&ref_topic=7332343).

Comment: Google Data Studio or Looker Studio doesn't support alerts...